# How can I merge two sound clips *without* crossfade to achieve a seamless transition?

Tags: editing

My audio editor doesn't support crossfade for some reason. Can I still merge two audio clips in it without having that annoying "stitching sound" at the seam of the two tracks? Thanks

Comment: If it has no cross fade function I’d feel strange calling it an audio editor. I suggest saving up for something else. Reaper is a very powerful and only USD 60.

Comment: And what "audio editor" is this, with no crossfade? If it doesn't have that basic feature, it also shouldn't have EQ, compression, plugin support, ... Maybe it can trim, if it does anything.

Get outa there and use an actual audio editor.

Comment: Well, it's a pretty good audio editor that is a. stable (never crashes), b. has a great UI, and c. does what I need it to do without requiring a manual.

Answer (score 3):

Not unless you join at a zero crossing; i.e.where the wave crosses the centre line & has 'no volume' [but then, all your edits should be at zero-crossing anyway].

Even Audacity has cross-fade. It's a pretty basic function.
https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/creating_a_crossfade.html

Comment: Thanks! That's really hard to accomplish though, especially if there are two channels. It took me a while to leave audacity because of its terrible UI so I don't think I'll be going back to it anytime soon.

Comment: We have no idea what you're working in or your method. This is, as already noted, pretty basic functionality for any audio editor, as without it… you get clicks.

Comment: @Zack As far as I can see you have three options, A) Just chop at different locations until you get lucky and there's no click, 2) Use a very short fade out and fade in to get your zero-crossing. D) Use a different editor to do it properly.